# Firebase query statement whereField(notIn) doesn't work

Tags: swift, firebase

Here is part of my code

```
db.collection("Activities").whereField("read", notIn: [Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]).limit(to: 10).getDocuments{ (querySnapshot, error)
```

I can see my uid is "Y31FESSEmZgb6F9mPQoQLrgymnQ2".

And here is my database pic

[image: database document]

However the query results stll have those data with this uid. It seems the query whereField compound doesn't work. How to fix it?

Comment: `read` "123" matches the condition

Comment: @DarkBee You are looking at the wrong field

Comment: @DarkBee the uid in pic is the "activity ID", and the uid in the code is user ID, they are different

Comment: @JoakimDanielson could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson but I set another document where read has only "Y3...Q2", it is still in getDocument results...

Answer (score 0):

When you call `whereField(_:notIn:)` you are comparing the `read` array to each element in the array you passed in as the `notIn` argument. The only element in the `notIn` array is a `uid` string. You are getting unexpected results because you are comparing an array (`read`) to a string (`uid`).

If I were you I would try using the `filter(using:)` method and see if that gives you what you want. This might be what you need:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (ANY read == %@)", Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
db.collection("Activities").filter(using: predicate)
```

Comment: Hi, Robert Crabtree! Thanks for your answer, but there is something wrong. The error says "Invalid query. Only compound queries using AND are supported." And app broke down. Could you please explain more?

Comment: @ZCJ_Caffrey Maybe you can try `NSPredicate(format: "NONE read == %@", Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)`

Comment: It is still invalid query... It is hard for a swift newer

Answer (score 0):

It seems "notIn" is a new command for firebase, and no clear example for what I want. So I use a clumsy method, which is manually set limit and then reaching limit will break loop. Use if array.contains to find whether it is existed in the array.